# Ember store.push with hasMany doesn't update template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Assuming the following **models**:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend(
  email: DS.attr('string')
  session_users: DS.hasMany('sessionUser')
)

App.SessionUser = DS.Model.extend(
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
  state: DS.attr('string')
  session: DS.belongsTo('session')
)

App.Session = DS.Model.extend(
  title: DS.attr('string')
  session_users: DS.hasMany('sessionUser')
)
```

The route **session_route.js.coffee**:

```
App.SessionRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: (params) ->
    this.store.find('session', params.id)
)
```

And the following **session.hbs** template:

```
{{#each session_users}}
    {{state}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm connected to a WebSocket stream, when a new SessionUser is created, I get notified.
Here **sessions_controller.js.coffee** to test pushing some payload:

```
payload =
    id: 20
    user: controller.store.getById('user', 2)
    session: controller.store.getById('session', 2)
    state: 'confirmed'
  controller.store.push('sessionUser', payload)
```

Using Ember Inspector(Chrome Extension) I can see the session user was pushed and is exists in the store with the right relationships, but the template wasn't updated.
When using *store.createRecord* the template is actually getting updated, but I want to use push/pushPayload so that I can use the existing serializers.

Comment: Your route looks like it's only finding a single session, but you are iterating over an array.

Comment: n/m, I see your session_users is a variable under the session.

Comment: If you call find right after the push does it load it?

Comment: the find function returns me the pushed sessionUser, but the template is still the same, why only createRecord affects the template?

Comment: if you use just the ids in the payload for user and session is it the same?

Comment: It seems that calling session.addRecord with the returned model of push, does update the template. Looks like the model is getting pushed but Ember doesn't add it to the ManyArray, is it a bug?

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure this is a known bug. We do something similar with a websocket: after we push the payload to create the record, we manually call `addObject` to add it to the hasMany relationship e.g.

```
var comment = store.push('comment', payload);
post.get('comments').addObject(comment);
```